# CSS on Mapbox Geocoder

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl, react-map-gl

I had a question about adding CSS, since I could not find any other issues related to this. I am trying to move the Geocoder Search farther down the map than where it is positioned at 'top-right' and I cannot change it's position, whether I use inline or internal CSS:

```
import React from "react";
import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";
import "react-map-gl-geocoder/dist/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css";
import Geocoder from "react-map-gl-geocoder";
const geostyle {
    margin: '20px';
}

const Map = () = > {`
...
return(
<div>
...
<Geocoder
    style={geostyle}
    mapRef={myMap}
    onViewportChange={setViewport}
    mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
    viewport={viewport}
    position="top-left"
  />
...
</div>
);
};
```

Is there a way to customize the Geocoder search bar? Would I have to edit the mapbox css that I imported from 'react-map-gl-geocoder? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, unfortunately you would have to go into the styles imported from mapbox and edit those. I found this question because I'm trying to see if there is an alternative, but it looks like there's not. Styling the geocoder is really frustrating for many reasons. I suggest sticking with the vanilla styling to avoid the headache, but if you must change the styling, you should copy the css found in `/@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/dist/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css` , paste it into another css file, and edit it there. I know i'm a year late, but have fun and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Mapbox GL JS and I'm customizing mapbox geocoder elements by customizing the mapbox CSS.

As you can see in this Mapbox Example "[Place the geocoder input outside the map](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder-outside-the-map/)", the position of the geocoder is changed by editing the Mapbox CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working sample:

[https://transparentgov.net:3200/mapbox10/default?layer_id=105&layer=Fire+Divisions&center_lat=34.049039&center_long=-118.246521&center_zoom=17&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.lacity.org%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2FMapping%2FNavigateLA%2FMapServer&panto=0](https://transparentgov.net:3200/mapbox10/default?layer_id=105&layer=Fire%20Divisions&center_lat=34.049039&center_long=-118.246521&center_zoom=17&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.lacity.org%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2FMapping%2FNavigateLA%2FMapServer&panto=0)

[image]

CSS is:
[image]

html (I use .pug, it is same as html just different format )

[image]

javascript is here:
[image]